# HTML File Upload With Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, servicestack

Simply put I need to be able to, using a file input field, select a file on my machine, hit an "Upload" button, and have the file uploaded (as a byte array perhaps, but that's server side stuff which I will worry about later) to a server. I have an UploadService created using ServiceStack, and now all I need to do is execute an $http post statement.

But wait! There's more!

My server requires a header { Authorization: AUTH_TOKEN_HERE } to be sent with the request.

I can use: jQuery, AngularJS, JavaScript, C#, and HTML. What to I do!?!?

Comment: The authorization header is usually called "Basic Auth".

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do that is to explicitly make an XMLHTTPRequest (AJAX call) with the auth header set. But the answer on this questions suggests you use the jQuery `$.ajax()` function along with a "beforeSend" function to authenticate: [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)